# Creating a sorted hash counting the occurrences of a number in an array

Tags: ruby

I figured something like this:

```
a= [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a.inj­ect({}) { |h, el| h[el]­ = a.cou­nt(el) if h[el]­.nil? ; h }.sor­t_by {|k,v­| v}.re­verse.inje­ct({}) { |h, el| h[el[­0]] = el[1]­ ; h}
```

This outputs:

```
=> {0=>10, 4=>9, 2=>5, 1=>4, 3=>2}
```

But it seems like a clunky solution that does to many passes over the "same" thing.

What would be a good way to do this from different viewpoints?

I.e:

1. an "impress your Java friends" (small one-liner not used in production)
2. Performance
3. Easily read

Comment: I think you need a longer array for a more representative benchmark. I don't know the big O for all of these, but there might be significant differences with a tougher dataset. What about `a = 1_000.times.map{ rand 9 }` ?

Comment: Great suggestion, I was thinking that enough iterations would be enough but clearly that was an error in thinking on my part.

Comment: Patrik, if you are worried about performance, you should use `each` and `sort_by!` (without reverse). Of course, that's awful imperative, non-declarative code.

Comment: memory consumption might vary, too. chaining group_by and map creates a hash with arrays as values then an array of arrays, while inject directly creates a hash with integers as keys and values.

Comment: Sacrificing some performance for readability seems to ruby way to go (in MRI atleast).

Comment: interesting results. I must admit i was convinced `inject` would be more efficient, but obviously it's not ! I guess using `Array#length` is more efficient than incrementing a counter, due to C implementation. Another lesson learned today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which viewpoint this would be, but this is what I came up with:

```
Hash[a.group_by {|e| e}.map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}]
```

Update: I'm not thrilled with this, but this one sorts by the occurrence count, descending.

```
Hash[a.group_by {|e| e}.map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}.sort_by {|a| a[1]}.reverse]
```

Comment: Hash[a.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }.sort.reverse] works, can you make it even cleaner? :)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you want it sorted descending by the occurrence count? The line in your comment doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: You are right. Hash[a.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }.sort_by { |a,b| b }.reverse] does though.

Comment: You can also write: `Hash[xs.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k, vs| [k, vs.length] }.sort_by { |k, length| -length }]`